# ActiveJobs Queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous

I have a RoR app with some model that need to do a provision to remote APIs. But in two of them, I need to do many provisioning HTTP requests and I use ActiveJob to this task.

The problem's what I need to maintain a creation order for these HTTP request, but ActiveJob doesn't.

How to process many async tasks with ActiveJob in a certain sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put those jobs on a special queue

```
class MyHttpJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :serial_creation
  #....
end
```

And have only one worker on that queue. No concurrency => automatic serialization. Of course, this has serious performance limitations. But if your one worker can handle the traffic, it's a good easy approach.